# Is there an implementation similar to Spring's CachingConnectionFactory that also closes idle connections until they are needed again?

Tags: java, spring, jms, solace

We are using Spring's CachingConnectionFactory to handle tens of millions of messages per day in production with our application and it works well.

We're looking to drop the amount of concurrent connections to Solace, however, until they are needed as we are sharing our ESB infrastructure with numerous other applications.  Is there a lazy extension of this Spring factory which achieves what we need?

Comment: It sounds like a problem about connection pool, such as apache commons-pool2 toolset. You can try to override this connection factory and try to obtain connections through commons-pool.

Answer (score 1):

The CachingConnectionFactory already does lazy creation of connections, and it's the responsibility of the app to explicitly close unused Sessions to return them to the pool, as outlined in the Spring docs.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.html

If this is for message consumers, it is preferable to let the listener container itself handle appropriate caching instead of a CachingConnectionFactory. The DefaultMessageListenerContainer supports dynamic scaling.

Comment: This is for a producer and we're using JmsTemplate which closes the session without us having to explicitly do so.

Answer (score 1):

I think what needs to be clarified here is the definition of "idle" - does it mean no messages are being consumed or produced for the remainder of the application's life?  Or just periodic inactivity, which may or may not be predictable in terms of duration of inactivity and/or when it occurs?  Moreover, as noted by the previous answer, lazy resource management refers to the creation of connections - not destroying them when "idle" - which could mean any number of things as noted earlier.

In general, message consumers usually will not be able to predict when their connection will be idle as messages can be received at any time.  For producers, you may have a better idea when your connection will be idle, although it is generally not worth the overhead of re-creating a new connection for every publish, as would be done using `JmsTemplate` without CCF / SCF.  In either case, the following may assist in resource management:

1. If the app performs periodic batch-type work and does not need to produce or consume data between runs with long delays in between, it may make sense to conserve resources either by explicitly managing resources (e.g. destroy / re-create CCF) or shutting down and restarting when needed - Spring Cloud Task may fit the bill, or perhaps a cron job.
2. Minimize the number of `@JmsListener` callbacks if possible, as each one will translate to a connection.  Solace queues support multiple subscriptions as well as wildcards, so it may be possible to consolidate subscriptions onto fewer queues.  If ordering is not an issue, a `concurrency` argument can be passed to `@JmsListener` to allow for round-robin processing among multiple consumers on the same connection.
3. Offload connections from the shared Solace broker to a dedicated broker for your application, and set up a VPN bridge or DMR (Dynamic Message Routing) to the shared broker.
4. The PubSub+ software broker supports a wide range of connection scaling tiers, from 100 to 200K, so you can select a tier that provides sufficient capacity.  This can either be done on your dedicated broker or the shared broker, or both, depending on your requirements and constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We're using JmsTemplate with CachingConnectionFactory to produce messages. My question is whether or not Spring releases the connection from Solace during periodic inactivity, or if a connection is maintained at all times with this setup? I think you address this in point 1 above. Edit, I see from the SingleConnectionFactory docs that it ignores all calls to Connection.close(). That answers that!